# Как правильно определить новый метод для существующего объекта по аналогии с Object.defineProperty() для свойств?

Tags: javascript

Сейчас использую такое решение:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", {
  value: (function prop() {
    // code
  })(),
});
```

Суть: добавить новое свойство, которое является callable существующему объекту.

По сути, я добавляю свойство. Но это свойство содержит значение (value), равное именованной самовыполняющейся функции. Такой способ работает, но я не уверен, что так делать рекомендуется. Думаю, есть более изящный способ. Вопрос - **какой именно?** Второй вопрос - **если делать так, как сделал я не рекомендуется, то почему?**

Comment: оно не "равное именованной самовыполняющейся функции", а равное тому, что эта функция возвращает в момент выполнение кода вопроса

Comment: @Igor но ведь конструкция вида `(function() {// code})()` как раз так и называется, как я указал? Или вы не об этом?

Comment: @smellyshovel вы можете с тем же успехом объявить эту функцию по нормальному, и вставить только её вызов (`value: prop() `)

Comment: А еще можно и вызвать её пораньше, записать результат в переменную, и засовывать в аргументы defineProperty эту переменную, с тем же результатом.

Comment: @Darth такой вариант я, вроде, проверял, и он не работал. При вызове `obj.prop()` ничего не происходило.

Comment: @smellyshovel я, собственно, не оспариваю название того, что стоит справа от `:`. *Метод* таким образом определить не получится, если только IIFE не возвращает другую функцию.

Comment: А ваша функция возвращает другую функцию?

Comment: @Darth нет. Я хочу пользоваться ей, как обычным геттером, которому можно передать параметр. По сути, мне просто метод определить надо. Хотя, если методом считать нечто, что изменяет состояние объекта, то мне и не метод нужен, а свойство, которое является, по сути, функцией, что-то возвращающей.

Comment: `obj.prop = function(){  ...  }` и выкидывайте из головы кашу.

Comment: @Darth блин, так можно было? XD

Comment: Вместо "самовыполняющейся функции" лично мне больше нравится термин "функциональное выражение", он смещает акцент с функции на выражение и подразумевает наличие результата в итоге

Comment: А вы зацепились видимо за эту "функцию" и забыли, что она самовыполняющаяся. Т.е. что итогом (в данном случае - `value`) будет не функция, а результат её работы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

```js
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", {
  value: function() {
    // code
    console.log("test");
  }
});

console.log("before calling freshly-defined method");
obj.prop();
```

Comment: Блин, ну не работает такой код. А мой работает почему-то. Может иметь влияние то, что я свойство прототипа задаю, а не просто объекта?

Comment: @smellyshovel Вы видите в ответе кнопку "Выполнить код"? Попробуйте ее нажать.

Comment: Я вижу, что здесь в примере все работает. Я вам говорю, что **у меня** такой вызов не отрабатывает. Судя по всему, намного логичнее будет сделать, как подсказал @Darth.

Comment: @smellyshovel Вы неправильно скопировали мой код

Comment: А так можно? XD
Я чую, что подвох где-то в другом

Comment: @smellyshovel Добавьте код, воспроизводящий "неработающее" поведение, в вопрос. Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода ..." в редакторе вопроса.

Comment: Извиняюсь, мой косяк был. Забыл, что код выполнятся как в коллбэке eventlistener'a. Но ближе к делу. Я правильно понимаю, что такой вариант предпочтительнее, если мне нужно добавить другие параметры вроде `writable`, `configurable`, а если это меня не интересует, то можно способ `obj.method = function() {};` использовать?

Comment: @smellyshovel совершенно верно

Comment: Ну как бы в любом случае - решение ваше, даже несмотря на то, что я просто был невнимателен. Спасибо, что натолкнули на дальнейшее расследование :D

Comment: Тогда спасибо, все ясно.